# How can define redirect inside of extendsRoutes of unplugin-vue-router?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite, vite-plugin-pages

I want to migrate from vite-plugin-pages to unplugin-vue-router. In router folder of my vue3 project, I've defined the following route config in my route folder based vite-plugin-pages as follows:

```
**
 * Route configuration
  const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),

  routes: [
    // ℹ️ We are redirecting to different pages based on role.
      {
      path: "/",
      redirect: (to) => {
        const isLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn();

        if (isLoggedIn) {
          return { name: "dashboards-analytics" };
        }

        return { name: "home" };
      },
    },
    ...setupLayouts(routes),
  ],
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 };
  },
});
```

I am seeking to use unplugin-vue-router instead, and implement the above approach in this plugin.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same case with you. This is how I solved it. Hope this can help you.

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  extendRoutes: routes => [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: to => {
        const authStore = useAuthStore()
        const { isLogged } = storeToRefs(authStore)

        return isLogged.value ? 
          { name: 'home' } : 
          { name: 'login', query: to.query }
      },
    },
    ...setupLayouts(routes),
  ],
})
```